# Network Interface does not contain a definition for ""

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, code-reuse, network-interface

I recently created this code for a WPF application that I was doing. The project where I'm reusing the code is a Windows 8 application. The code itself is the same so I don't really see what could be the issue. The only difference between them is of course the application and the .NET Framework being used. In the WPF application I was targeting .NET 3.0 and for the Windows 8 application I'm using .NET 4.5.

As you can tell this is an extension method:

```
public static bool isTunnel(this NetworkInterface adapter)
        {
            return adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel;
        }
```

The error it gives for that method is:

```
Error   3   'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface' does not contain a definition for 'NetworkInterfaceType' and no extension method 'NetworkInterfaceType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   4   The name 'NetworkInterfaceType' does not exist in the current context
```

In my model class I'm having a similar issue. On this line:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
```

it causes an error saying that the GetAllNetworkInterfaces() does not exist in NetworkInterface. Here's the exact error:

```
Error   15  'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface' does not contain a definition for 'GetAllNetworkInterfaces'
```

Is there something that I don't know about reusing code from WPF application in Windows 8 applications?

**Update:** Using the ianainterfacetype I was able to fix half of my extension methods because I was able to tell if they were Ethernet, Wireless, or Tunnel. I'm still searching for a way to tell if they were created by VirtualBox or VMware.

For those who want to know about the ianainterfacetype you can find info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.ianainterfacetype.aspx).

Comment: This may help you get started with WinRT's network API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336521/query-local-ip-address/10456778#10456778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetAllNetworkInterfaces` is not available to Windows Store (metro) apps. The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k056bfdz.aspx) indicates that only the `GetIsNetworkAvailable` method is available to Windows Store apps. The green briefcase indicates whether or not it is available to Windows Store apps.

I am not aware of any API that is available to Windows Store apps that can give you the information you are looking for.

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted Unfortunately I think not.

Comment: I don’t remember. That was 5 years ago. I’ll look for my old code if I find it then I’ll report back.