# Windows Store App (C#/Xaml) retrieve ip addresses

Tags: c#, xaml, networking, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

First of all i am a begginer in Windows store app development. I am trying to develop an application (C#/Xaml) that retrieves a list of ip addresses,(if its possible) mac addresses of all devices that are connected to my network something similar to **Fing** (is available in Appstore/Play store but not in Windows store)

https://itunes.apple.com/gr/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107?mt=8

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing

The problem is that i cant find any available API in WinRT in contrast with .NET that has the right APIs and methods for this job.

Comment: Take a look at accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336521/query-local-ip-address) question. This may be not exactly what you are looking for, but a good point to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions like `GetIpNetTable` are not currently exposed within the Windows Runtime.  In fact, most of the deep [IP Helper Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are not exposed, and cannot be accessed. As such, writing the equivalent style application will be extremely difficult without an external application hosted elsewhere that did the work. You might be able to do some general network scans, but that won't be as effective.

(I'm not sure that there were equivalent classes in .NET either. The native Win32 API calls were available from managed code.)